# Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: xamarin.forms, targetinvocationexception

Getting the below exception when trying to send a string value through `MessagingCenter`. The exception is on a **PopupPage**.

**Exception Details:**

> exception:>>System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at CatholicBrain.Views.BibleOrderGamePage.<.ctor>b__3_0 (CatholicBrain.Model.BibleOrderGameViewModel s, System.String answer) [0x00001] in F:\My Projects\Xamarin\catholicbrain-mobile-app\CatholicBrain\CatholicBrain\Views\BibleOrderGamePage.xaml.cs:30 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00086] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
>     at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter+Subscription.InvokeCallback (System.Object sender, System.Object args) [0x00064] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\MessagingCenter.cs:94 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.InnerSend (System.String message, System.Type senderType, System.Type argType, System.Object sender, System.Object args) [0x0006b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\MessagingCenter.cs:217 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Xamarin.Forms.IMessagingCenter.Send[TSender,TArgs] (TSender sender, System.String message, TArgs args) [0x00013] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\MessagingCenter.cs:115 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send[TSender,TArgs] (TSender sender, System.String message, TArgs args) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\MessagingCenter.cs:108 
>     at CatholicBrain.Model.BibleOrderGameViewModel.StartBibleOrderCheck (CatholicBrain.Model.BibleOrderAnswer selectedItem, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] rightAnswerList) [0x00114] in F:\My Projects\Xamarin\catholicbrain-mobile-app\CatholicBrain\CatholicBrain\Model\BibleOrderGameViewModel.cs:195

**MessagingCenter.Send**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<BibleOrderGameViewModel, string>(this, "rightanswer", selectedItem.Answer);
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
```

**MessagingCenter.Subscribe**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BibleOrderGameViewModel, string>(this, "rightanswer", (s, answer) =>
{
    answerLabel.Text = answer;
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you using the Messaging Center for?

Comment: @FreakyAli I am trying to send a string value from one page and subscribe it on another page, I have edited the question with MessagingCenter.Subscribe code.

Comment: You could rewrite the constructor and pass the string as Params when init the popup page .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Can you give a code sample? I didn't get completly.

Comment: Did you use the plugin `Rg.Plugins.Popup` ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes

Comment: You can use `Object` instead of `BibleOrderGameViewModel` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204783/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: if you actually read the stack trace, you'll see "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at CatholicBrain.Views.BibleOrderGamePage."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe` code in `OnDisappearing()` on the same page which contains the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` code.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<BibleOrderGameViewModel, string>(this, "rightanswer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use this when sending a message, the object you send must be separated from the Page.
Have you tried using a marker class instead of object?

refer this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102443/system-reflection-targetinvocationexception-on-messagingcenter-send)

Comment: I am trying to send a string value from one page and subscribe it on another page, I have edited the question with MessagingCenter.Subscribe code.